# Why is thrust reduce_by_key almost 75x slower than for_each with atomicAdd()?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cuda, thrust

I was not satisfied with the performance of the below `thrust::reduce_by_key`, so I rewrote it in a variety of ways with little gained benefit (including removing the permutation iterator). However, it wasn't until after replacing it with a `thrust::for_each()` (see below) that capitalizes on `atomicAdd()`, that I gained almost a 75x speedup! The two versions produce the exact same results. **What could be the biggest cause for the dramatic performance differences?**

Complete code for comparison between the two approaches:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/discard_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>

constexpr int NumberOfOscillators = 100;
int SeedRange = 500;

struct GetProduct
{
    template<typename Tuple>
    __host__ __device__
        int operator()(const Tuple & t)
    {
        return  thrust::get<0>(t) * thrust::get<1>(t);
    }
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace thrust::placeholders;
    
    /* BEGIN INITIALIZATION */

    thrust::device_vector<int> dv_OscillatorsVelocity(NumberOfOscillators);
    thrust::device_vector<int> dv_outputCompare(NumberOfOscillators);
    thrust::device_vector<int> dv_Connections_Strength((NumberOfOscillators - 1) * NumberOfOscillators);
    thrust::device_vector<int> dv_Connections_Active((NumberOfOscillators - 1) * NumberOfOscillators);
    thrust::device_vector<int> dv_Connections_TerminalOscillatorID_Map(0);
    thrust::device_vector<int> dv_Permutation_Connections_To_TerminalOscillators((NumberOfOscillators - 1) * NumberOfOscillators);
    thrust::device_vector<int> dv_Connection_Keys((NumberOfOscillators - 1) * NumberOfOscillators);
    
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    thrust::fill(dv_OscillatorsVelocity.begin(), dv_OscillatorsVelocity.end(), 0);

    for (int c = 0; c < NumberOfOscillators * (NumberOfOscillators - 1); c++)
    {
        dv_Connections_Strength[c] = (rand() % SeedRange) - (SeedRange / 2);

        dv_Connections_Active[c] = 0;
    }

    int curOscillatorIndx = -1;
    for (int c = 0; c < NumberOfOscillators * NumberOfOscillators; c++)
    {
        if (c % NumberOfOscillators == 0)
        {
            curOscillatorIndx++;
        }

        if (c % NumberOfOscillators != curOscillatorIndx)
        {
            dv_Connections_TerminalOscillatorID_Map.push_back(c % NumberOfOscillators);
        }
    }

    for (int n = 0; n < NumberOfOscillators; n++)
    {
        for (int p = 0; p < NumberOfOscillators - 1; p++)
        {
            thrust::copy_if(
                thrust::device,
                thrust::make_counting_iterator<int>(0),
                thrust::make_counting_iterator<int>(dv_Connections_TerminalOscillatorID_Map.size()), // indices from 0 to N
                dv_Connections_TerminalOscillatorID_Map.begin(), // array data
                dv_Permutation_Connections_To_TerminalOscillators.begin() + (n * (NumberOfOscillators - 1)), // result will be written here
                _1 == n);
        }
    }

    for (int c = 0; c < NumberOfOscillators * (NumberOfOscillators - 1); c++)
    {
        dv_Connection_Keys[c] = c / (NumberOfOscillators - 1);
    }

    /* END INITIALIZATION */


    /* BEGIN COMPARISON */

    auto t = clock();

    for (int x = 0; x < 5000; ++x) //Set x maximum to a reasonable number while testing performance.
    {
        thrust::reduce_by_key(
            thrust::device,
            //dv_Connection_Keys = 0,0,0,...1,1,1,...2,2,2,...3,3,3...
            dv_Connection_Keys.begin(), //keys_first    The beginning of the input key range.
            dv_Connection_Keys.end(), //keys_last   The end of the input key range.
            thrust::make_permutation_iterator(
                thrust::make_transform_iterator(
                    thrust::make_zip_iterator(
                        thrust::make_tuple(
                            dv_Connections_Strength.begin(),
                            dv_Connections_Active.begin()
                        )
                    ),
                    GetProduct()
                ),
                dv_Permutation_Connections_To_TerminalOscillators.begin()
            ), //values_first   The beginning of the input value range.
            thrust::make_discard_iterator(), //keys_output  The beginning of the output key range.
            dv_OscillatorsVelocity.begin() //values_output  The beginning of the output value range.
        );
    }

    std::cout << "iterations    time for original: " << (clock() - t) * (1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << "ms\n" << endl << endl;

    thrust::copy(dv_OscillatorsVelocity.begin(), dv_OscillatorsVelocity.end(), dv_outputCompare.begin());


    t = clock();

    for (int x = 0; x < 5000; ++x) //Set x maximum to a reasonable number while testing performance.
    {
        thrust::for_each(
            thrust::device,
            thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),
            thrust::make_counting_iterator(0) + dv_Connections_Active.size(),
            [
                s = dv_OscillatorsVelocity.size() - 1,
                dv_b = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(dv_OscillatorsVelocity.data()),
                dv_c = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(dv_Permutation_Connections_To_TerminalOscillators.data()), //3,6,9,0,7,10,1,4,11,2,5,8
                dv_ppa = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(dv_Connections_Active.data()),
                dv_pps = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(dv_Connections_Strength.data())
            ] __device__(int i) {
                const int readIndex = i / s;
                atomicAdd(
                    dv_b + readIndex,
                    (dv_ppa[dv_c[i]] * dv_pps[dv_c[i]])
                );
            }
        );
    }

    std::cout << "iterations    time for new: " << (clock() - t) * (1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << "ms\n" << endl << endl;

    std::cout << "***" << (dv_OscillatorsVelocity == dv_outputCompare ? "success" : "fail") << "***\n";

    /* END COMPARISON */

    return 0;
}
```

**Extra info.:**

My results are using a single GTX 980 TI.

There are 100 * (100 - 1) = 9,900 elements in all of the "Connection" vectors.

Each of the 100 unique keys found in dv_Connection_Keys has 99 elements each.

Use this compiler option: --expt-extended-lambda

Comment: The traditional question to usually mal-formed benchmark questions on SO: how do you compile, what compiler flags, optimizations and libraries are used.

Comment: For performance questions, I suggest providing a complete test case.

Comment: I think mentioning "thrust" is sufficient for libraries, no? Also, I updated the "Extra Info" section with the compiler option needed.

@RobertCrovella, working on that now.

Comment: Complete code added for review. Somehow it now takes 15000ms to run the reduce_by_key, and only 40ms to run the for_each with atomicAdd() solution.

Comment: Are you building a debug project?  When I run your code I get a ~3x difference in performance.  "original" = 210ms, "new" = 70ms.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, those numbers were in a debug build. I switched to release mode and get 466ms and 27ms, respectively for original and new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What could be the biggest cause for the dramatic performance differences?

You are evidently building a debug project, that is your compilation settings include the `-G` switch.  Although you were asked for your compilation settings in the comments, you didn't mention this.

It's important.

CUDA device code can have dramatically different performance characteristics when compiled with `-G`.

**Don't evaluate performance of a debug project, or code compiled with `-G`**.

When I compile and run your code without `-G`, I get:

```
iterations    time for original: 210ms


iterations    time for new: 70ms


***success***
```

When I compile your code with the debug switch  `-G`, and run, I get:

```
iterations    time for original: 12330ms


iterations    time for new: 320ms


***success***
```

returning to your question, that accounts for the biggest factor of the difference.

Comment: +1, marked as answer for being technically true. I'm still getting 466ms and 27ms, respectively for original and new, which is now a 17x difference. I'm thinking that remaining discrepancy could be due to having a small dataset, combined with the fact that reduce_by_key does not assume row size.

Comment: does not assume that each row has the same length*

Comment: I don't get anything like a 17x difference when I run your code as posted on a Tesla V100, CUDA 11.4. As I show in my answer, its 3x.  I doubt that there would be any reason to conclude that a GTX 980Ti is ~2.5x faster than a V100, so it might be that CUDA version or some other difference not yet uncovered is contributing to the discrepancy.  Thrust relative performance in many cases can be predicted by counting the number of reads and writes.  It's possible that the atomic method has a ~3x improvement in number of reads and writes.  I don't think so for ~17x.

Answer (score 2):

The following answer tries to explain or at least motivate the remaining difference in performance after going from a debug build to a release build as explained in Robert Crovella's answer.

#### Coalescing

As the accesses in both kernels are not [coalesced](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/how-access-global-memory-efficiently-cuda-c-kernels/) due to the `permutation_iterator`/indirection through `dv_c`, going by the the plain number of accesses will overestimate the performance in this case. `thrust::reduce_by_key` (or pretty much all Thrust algorithms) is not and can not be optimized for general permutations of the input as the performance of these bandwidth-bound kernels depends strongly on coalesced memory access. Naturally the algorithms are written such that accesses are coalesced for normal continuous input. So if you need to access the permuted state order of the data more than once (which might happen in a single reduction algorithm), it could be faster to actually permute the data in memory using `thrust::gather` or `thrust::scatter` once so at least all following accesses are efficient. I would not expect the `for_each` solution to beat `reduce_by_key` without that permutation.

#### Atomics

Newer versions of `nvcc` will try to use automatically use [warp-aggregated-atomics](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-optimized-filtering-warp-aggregated-atomics/) to reduce the number of actual atomic instructions on the same address. As neighboring threads (same warp) tend to atomically write to the same address, this optimization is crucial for the performance of your custom reduction. Another important detail is that `s = NumberOfOscillators` is relatively small (`100`) in your code compared to typical thread-block sizes (`256`, `512`, `1024`; locality of atomic writes) and the amount of parallelism in the `for_each` (~`NumberOfOscillators`^2). So for smaller `NumberOfOscillators` I expect your custom reduction to get worse than `reduce_by_key` due to the vanishing amount of parallelism, while for bigger `NumberOfOscillators` you get both much more parallelism and more thread blocks/warps writing to the same location, so it is not quite clear which one will win without benchmarking it for given hardware and compiler.